# Native module cannot be null - React Native, Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I made expo initial app
My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import NfcManager, {NfcEvents} from 'react-native-nfc-manager';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

When I trying to import NFC manager Im getting error: Native module cannot be null
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWOfX.png)

Google said that its error with IOS notifications, Im coding from windows VScode and cannot link push notifications, how I can solve this error? I cannot code without expo because this is only one way to simulate my app from windows on iphone as I understand

Answer (score 0):

I solve it: expo not allowing additional libraries

Comment: Please provide more details in the answer on how this resolved your issue.